# error with nativescript-geolocation plugin

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, java-native-interface, nativescript

i'm having a error with google maps when trying to enable location.

iv'e installed google-maps-sdk and configured it in the project bot something went wrong.

what can be the problem? it's the first time i see this error.

- this is the error

```
ERROR Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT).
JS: =======
JS: Check the 'adb logcat' for additional information about the error.
JS: =======
JS: ERROR Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT).
JS: =======
JS: Check the 'adb logcat' for additional information about the error.
JS: =======
JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot enable the location service. Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT).
JS: =======
JS: Check the 'adb logcat' for additional information about the error.
JS: =======
```

- package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.DoHere",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.2.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "nativescript-angular": "^8.2.2",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^2.8.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats your gradle version?

Comment: where can i check the gradle version ? at the gradle-wrapper.properties file i see only {runtimeGradleVersion} and at the build.gradle file i see {runtimeAndroidPluginVersion}  so where can i see the version?

Comment: How did you install Gradle, if you have Android Studio then you may check the version of Gradle form there. If gradle is accessible from your CLI, you can do `gradle --version`.

Comment: iv'e installed gradle when i installed android studio. my gradle version is 5.4.1 according to project structure in android studio. and the gradle is not accessible from my cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was at the configuration.
i added a file before-plugins.gradle

- before-plugins.gradle

```
android {
  project.ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.0"
  }
}
```

it's working now. 
thank you @Manoj

Comment: Where did you add the file ?

Comment: Ok ! I didn't notice everything is explained here => https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation#version-conflicts--google-play-services

Comment: Where have you found that file? in nativescript project i cannot find such file

Comment: i created the file at this path : App_Resources/Android/before-plugins.gradle @Vytautas Pranskunas